# Look-up table in C# with Types and Actions

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods, types, lookup-tables

I want to change my many if to a look-up table.

I have types and methods. I want to pair them.

```
if (propertyType == typeof(bool) || propertyType == typeof(bool?))
DoBool(propertyType);

if (propertyType == typeof(DateTime) || propertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
DoDateTime(propertyType);

if (propertyType == typeof(Guid) || propertyType == typeof(Guid?))
DoGuid(propertyType);
```

I have to create a `Dictionary<Type, Action>()`? Or which is the best elegant way to do this?

Can you offer me some suggestion where can I start or where can I find the solution?

Comment: You can certainly create a `Dictionary<Type, Action<Type>>` - that sounds like what you want from what you've shown us.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you, when I created this Dictionary how can I use it instead of if statements?

Comment: `if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(myType, out var action)) action(myType);`: check if there's an `action` for a given type (`myType`) and if it is, execute the `action`

Comment: If you're confident there will always be an entry, you can just use `dictionary[propertyType].Invoke(propertyType)`. Otherwise you'd want to use `TryGetValue` and invoke the value only if there's an entry. Given that the `propertyType` is the key anyway, you could use a `Dictionary<Type, Action>` and just register actions that will pass the appropriate argument where necessary, of course. It's hard to know what's best without seeing what your methods do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the answer you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own implementation which is little bit different, but I used @DaggeJ suggestion, so thanks!

First I created a base handler class. After that I used this base on different type classes. You can see it below.

**BaseClass:**

```
public abstract class QueryHandler<T> where T : class
{
    //I added here more property. 

    public abstract Type[] Types { get; }

    protected QueryHandler(//Properties)
    {
        //Properties null check
    }

    public abstract IQueryable<T> Handle();
}
```

**Descendant class:**

```
internal class GuidQuery<T> : QueryHandler<T> where T : class
{
    public override Type[] Types => new Type[] { typeof(Guid), typeof(Guid?) };

    public GuidQuery(//Properties) : base(//Properties)
    {
    }

    public override IQueryable<T> Handle()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
{
    var queryHandlerList = new List<QueryHandler<T>>()
    {
        new IntQuery<T>(//Properties),
        new DateTimeQuery<T>(//Properties),
        new StringQuery<T>(//Properties),
        new BoolQuery<T>(//Properties),
        new GuidQuery<T>(//Properties),
        new EnumQuery<T>(//Properties)
    };
}

return query = queryHandlerList.FirstOrDefault(h => GetType<T>(h, property.PropertyType)).Handle();

private bool GetType<T>(QueryHandler<T> handler, Type type) where T: class
{
    if (handler.Types.FirstOrDefault(t => t == type) == type || handler.Types.FirstOrDefault(t => t == type.BaseType) == type.BaseType) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is more about controlling the flow of the code than pure lookup, I would probably use an object oriented approach and put the code for each "handler" inside separate classes (with common stuff inside a base class).

You can create a common interface like

```
public interface ITypeHandler {
    void HandleType(Type type);
}
```

... and put the implementation of the handlers inside a dictionary of type `Dictionary<Type, ITypeHandler>` if you like, or you can have a property on the interface revealing which type it handles and select from a list of (perhaps Dependency Injected) handlers based on this property.

This adds benefits such as separation of concerns, testability, etc.

(Note that *Handler isn't a very good name, you will have to create a better name based on the scenario you're covering.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary<Type, Action<Type>>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Type>>() {
    {typeof(bool), DoBool},
    {typeof(bool?), DoBool},
    {typeof(DateTime), DoDateTime},
    {typeof(Datetime?), DoDateTime},
    {typeof(Guid), DoGuid},
    {typeof(Guid?), DoGuid}
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
dict[propertyType](propertyType)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method for initializing your lookup table with the specified type, to avoid repeating.

```
private readonly IDictionary<Type, Action<Type>> _lookup;
```

then you can define method for initializing the `_dict`,

```
private void AddEntry<T>(Action<Type> action) where T : struct
{       
    _lookup[typeof(T)] = action;
    _lookup[typeof(Nullable<T>)] = action;
}

private void DoInt(Type type) { /* implementation */ }

AddEntry<bool>(type => { /* implementation */ });
AddEntry<int>(DoInt);
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I'll mixed when I found and this is enough to start my own solution.